# Fantasy series with a female main character in which the cost of using magic depends on the strength of the spell

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, urban-fantasy

I’m trying to recall the name of a fantasy novel or series I read over a decade ago.

Here’s what I remember:

- Female main character (MC).
- Cost of using magic depends on the strength of the spell.
- MC would cast small spells and trade it off for a headache or something minor the next day; she had a mantra she recited in her head.
- There was a restaurant where the waitresses used glamour and the death row inmates would bear the price of the magic.
- MC went to some place and met a dude who specialized in being a lightning rod or something and would willingly bear the cost of powerful magic (she would try casting spells and he’d be getting broken bones in real time and smiling or something).
- I feel like there was a mysterious guy who suddenly popped up and something about a gate opening up at the end of the novel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm... did she lose memories with stronger magic, and had the ability to smell magic?

Comment: I can’t remember, sorry. I really can’t recall anything more than I’ve listed..

Comment: Your question has been closed as a Duplicate. This is not a censure, but more of a book-keeping measure that we do for [tag:sotry-identification] questions which share answers. You will still get points for upvotes, and people can comment on the questions and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I this the ***[Allie Beckstrom](https://www.goodreads.com/series/45779-allie-beckstrom)*** series by Devon Monk...?

[image: Front cover of "Magic to the Bone" (2008) by Devon Monk.]

The main character, Allie Beckstrom, is female and the Goodreads blurb for the first book, *[Magic to the Bone](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3241366-magic-to-the-bone)* (2008), indicates that the story is set in a world where all magic has costs, including migraines and memory loss.

> Allie would rather moonlight as a Hound than accept the family fortune - and the strings that come with it. All magic use has costs -- hers include migraines and memory loss. She finds a boy dying from a magic Offload with her father's signature, then her father is murdered. Allie's search for the truth calls on her country friend and the handsome man originally assigned as her bodyguard. Someone is forging magic signatures -- and hers is on her dead father.

The following excerpt from the [Google Books preview](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Magic_to_the_Bone/3Qotg7VKdUoC?hl=en&gbpv=0) of the first book also mentions Grounding, which is when one person acts as a "lightning rod" for another magic user, bearing most of the costs of the other user's magic to ease the burden placed on them.

> Grounding was another matter altogether. It was equivalent to acting as a lightning rod for someone else and was usually done while the original caster was drawing on magic. It allowed a larger amount of magic to be accessed, and a smaller price to be paid by the original caster. The Grounder often bore a heavier burden of the pain—trying to match another person's magical style and ability was very difficult and dangerous. And so was using Grounding to mitigate the pain of using magic.

Comment: :) That's the series I was thinking of, but couldn't remember the lightning rod scenario. If so, it would technically be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266491/novel-where-the-main-character-accidentally-gives-sentience-to-a-gargoyle